# angularjs $scope.$watch causes FireFox to do a complete reload

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple `watch` on a local scope variable that is to make query to update a json array when the value changes. This works fine in Chrome and IE11.  However in FireFox the watch causes the entire page to reload thus loosing any data that might have been collected.

The radio is in a ui-bootstrap-tpls accordian header.  Here is a plunker with the details.

http://plnkr.co/edit/10mS8azqb2OkueNdGuus

The Plunker has 4 sections.

1. Radio in Accordion w/o any function to stop propagation
2. Radio in body of Accordion
3. Radio in According Header with function
4. Radio in the Body of the 2nd Accordion

The Radio in #1 causes the accordion to close but will not set value.
Items #2 and $4 work as expected (Watch the console log).
Item #3 causes the session to restart in Firefox.

No errors are presented in Firebug's console.  It just reloads.

I am need to prevent the accordion from closing so I can set the value of the radio.  Firefox does not like the function calling `$event.stopPropagation();`

Any suggestions?

Thanks as always.

Comment: What happens when you change the template to not use `<a>` as we suggested - as a temporary workaround?

Comment: I have yet to try. I will get to it this week